# how to Save the Child Form textbox Values in MdiParent form Button Click Event?

Tags: .net, sql-server, c#-4.0, mdichild, mdiparent

I inserted mdiparent form in my project.It contains one child form(Customer Data Entry) with textboxes.In parent form one toolstrip button(Save Record).At the time of pressing the Save Record Button I want to Save the Customer Data Entry form Values(Child form Text Box values) in to Database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create public getter properties in you child form, accessing the respective text-box.
So you can access the property values from text-boxes, when you have the form's object initialized & not disposed.

Comment: Your answer would be much more useful for the asker and future readers if you could add the code that demonstrates your claim.

Comment: That is absolutely true but hints should be comments, not answers.